# (Not-Json data + Json data) to Json data

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I got my data from the server. I need to JSON decode them, before I use it. The problem is, the response data contains some extra text data too. So, when I use

```
String/ Iterable decodedData = json.decode(responseData)/ jsonDecode(responseData);
```

It gives me an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

My response from the server:

```
Message has been sent{"unique_id":"2021080504511401","role_id":3,"category_id":"1","first_name":"Nasir","phone":"23423423430","nid":"234234234","f_name":"sadfasdf","blood_group":"AB+","profession":"Farmer","gender":"female","address":"asdfasdfasdf","image":null,"district_id":null,"upazilla_id":"1","union_id":null,"email":"alskdsfjserdf@gmail.com","updated_at":"2021-08-05T10:51:14.000000Z","created_at":"2021-08-05T10:51:14.000000Z","id":60}
```

I need to get the object only. I can remove the non-used string data by accessing the index. But what if the text before the object is dynamic? I need a stable solution now.

Comment: My suggestion would be to include this piece of dynamic text into your JSON object `{"msg": "your msg"}` . This needs to be handled from the API team !

Answer (score 0):

I prepared an example for you, I hope it solves your problem.

```dart
  final response = '''
  Message has been sent{"unique_id":"2021080504511401","role_id":3,"category_id":"1","first_name":"Nasir","phone":"23423423430","nid":"234234234","f_name":"sadfasdf","blood_group":"AB+","profession":"Farmer","gender":"female","address":"asdfasdfasdf","image":null,"district_id":null,"upazilla_id":"1","union_id":null,"email":"alskdsfjserdf@gmail.com","updated_at":"2021-08-05T10:51:14.000000Z","created_at":"2021-08-05T10:51:14.000000Z","id":60}
  ''';
  final objectStartIndex = response.indexOf('{');
  final objectData = response.substring(objectStartIndex);
  final decodedData = jsonDecode(objectData);
  print('Result: $decodedData');
```